# FPC package: Flexmixedruns with binomial/multinomial categorial variables

Tags: r

I am using the `flexmixedruns` function from the `fpc` package and I am getting a 
`flexmix error` when I try to run the function.

My data set has both continuous and categorial data, but most of my categorial data has just 2 levels (`"Y"` or `"N"`).  Some of my variables have several levels.  I am wondering if I am getting the error because the function is treating all of my categorial variables as multinomial distributions.

Does anyone have experience working with this function?

#### reproducible example

```
#####  check for fpc package
required.packages <- c("fpc")
new.packages <- 
  required.packages[!(required.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])] 
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
rm(required.packages, new.packages)

library(fpc)

#####  create data set
df <- matrix(
  data=c("widget1", "widget2", "widget3", "widget4", "widget5", "widget6",
                    58, 18, 31, 130, 40, 31, 
                    70, 19, 44, 120, 57, 50,
                    "1E6", "1E5", "1E4", "1E6", "1E5", "1E4",
                    "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y",
                    "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y"), 
             nrow=6, ncol=6)

df <- as.data.frame(x=df)
row.names(df) <- df[, 1]
df <- df[, -1]
colnames(df) <- c("cont1", "cont2", "multi1", "bin1", "bin2")

df$cont1 <- as.numeric(df$cont1)
df$cont2 <- as.numeric(df$cont2)

#####  model
mdl <-
  flexmixedruns(x=df, xvarsorted=TRUE, continuous=2, discrete=3, simruns=5,
                n.cluster=3, recode=TRUE)
```

#### error message

```
Error in summary(flexout[[optimalk]]) : 
    error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in flexout[[optimalk]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

Comment: show us the code you already ran! like this it is hard to figure what you are trying to do!

Comment: That's all the error says? "flexmix error"?

Comment: Updated with reproducible example.  The actually data set has about 2000 observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the data formatting. The function appears to not be able to handle factor data initially, although the documentation says that it can take anything for categorical data that can be converted into a factor variable.

```
df$multi1 = as.numeric(df$multi1)
df$bin1 = as.numeric(df$bin1)
df$bin2 = as.numeric(df$bin2)

mdl <-flexmixedruns(x=df, xvarsorted=TRUE, continuous=2, discrete=3, simruns=5,
                n.cluster=3, recode=TRUE)

summary(df)
     cont1       cont2         multi1       bin1          bin2    
 Min.   :1   Min.   :1.0   Min.   :1   Min.   :1.0   Min.   :1.0  
 1st Qu.:2   1st Qu.:2.0   1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.:1.0  
 Median :3   Median :3.5   Median :2   Median :1.5   Median :1.5  
 Mean   :3   Mean   :3.5   Mean   :2   Mean   :1.5   Mean   :1.5  
 3rd Qu.:4   3rd Qu.:5.0   3rd Qu.:3   3rd Qu.:2.0   3rd Qu.:2.0  
 Max.   :5   Max.   :6.0   Max.   :3   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :2.0 

# k=  3  new best fit found in run  1 
# Nonoptimal or repeated fit found in run  2 
# k=  3  new best fit found in run  3 
# Nonoptimal or repeated fit found in run  4 
# Nonoptimal or repeated fit found in run  5 
# k=  3  BIC=  216462.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed debugging it is impossible to say for sure. Make sure the methods package is loaded, i.e.

```
library(methods)
```